Passing table name and filter as a variable in Databricks notebook
My python code in databricks notebook
qty_table = customer_master.customer_qty
customer_id = 1000

cust_qty = spark.sql("select count(*) from ${qty_table} where id = ${customer_id}").collect()[0][0]

This gives error.
Expecting to give me value in cust_qty

The value of qty_table is a string so it should be in quotes.
FOr the sql formatting you can use python formatting to replace the parameters like so.
qty_table = "customer_master.customer_qty"
customer_id = 1000

cust_qty = spark.sql(f"select count(*) from {qty_table} where id = {customer_id}").collect()[0][0]

